# cross deletion of messages

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, messaging

I have built very simple messaging system which works fine however I have a little problem.
When inserting a new message to the table I am associating that message with the username who sent it and when the user who sent the message deletes that message, the message is also deleted from the recipient.

I want the message only to be deleted from the sender. I update the table and set the message first as `deleted = 'yes'` before doing the actual delete. Can someone hint me just an idea?

table structure

id, from_user, to_user, subject, message, deleted, sent, date

```
$delete =$mysqli prepare("update messages set deleted = 'yes' where from_user = ?  and id = ? ");
$delete->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $id);
 foreach  ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
$delete->execute();
```

The actual delete...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE  FROM messages where from_user = ?  and id = ?  or to_user = ? and id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username->username, $id, $username->username, $id);
 foreach  ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a message until everyone associated with that message chooses to delete it, if they can.  If they can't, you can never delete messages unless you age them out based on some other criteria.

I'd probably have 3 tables if it was me:

```
user(userid, etc.)
message(messageid, text, etc.)
message_user(userid, messageid, role, deleted, etc.)
```

`role` would be `sender` or `recipient`. `deleted` would be `true` or `false`.

But that basic idea -- you need to couple your `delete` state with the user+message, and not with just the sender or just the recipient(s).

Answer (score 0):

Simple idea :p

Tables needed:

### Message

id, content, lastmodified_time

### MessageUser

id, UserId, MessageId, DeliveryType, Deleted

i.e:

**Message:**

1, Test Message, 2013-10-31 00:00:00

**MessageUser**

1, 11999, 1, 'Outgoing', 0

2, 12585, 1, 'Incoming', 1